# “TypeError: PushNotifier is not a constructor” when using node-pushnotifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I tried to send a message with [node-pushnotifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifier) in an `.mjs` file. The import does not work. The error I get:

```
const instance = new PushNotifier({
                 ^

TypeError: PushNotifier is not a constructor
    at file:///c:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/PR/Untis%20Api%20Call%20To%20Push%20Notify/Test-send.mjs:6:18
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:146:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:165:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

This is the code I used:

```js
import PushNotifier from "node-pushnotifier"

const instance = new PushNotifier({
  "api_token": "API-TOKEN",
  "package": "PACKAGE",
  "app_token": "APP-TOKEN"
})

instance.login("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
  .then(user => {
    // Set app token for instance (or create a new one).
    instance.setAppToken(user.getAppToken())

    // Iterate through devices.
    instance.getDevices()
      .then(devices => {
        // List devices.
        for (const device of devices) {
          console.log(device.getTitle() + " (" + device.getModel() + ")")
        }

        // Send text to all devices.
        instance.sendText(devices, "Hello from node :D")
      })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Oops, something went wrong.
  })
```

I already installed the package in VS Code:

```bash
npm i node-pushnotifier
```

I would like to receive a push notification from this package on my phone. I can’t use Python because it is not compatible with my other code.

Comment: What does `console.log(PushNotifier)` reveal?

Comment: If it's not a constructor, remove the `new` keyword and see what happens next.

Comment: @SebastianSimon

console.log reveals:


{
  default: [Function: PushNotifier] {
    Device: [Function: Device],
    User: [Function: User],
    AppToken: [Function: AppToken] { fromDisk: [Function (anonymous)] }
  }
}

Comment: @SterlingArcher

Then i get the error:
TypeError: PushNotifier is not a function

Comment: The real issue seems to be that `./node-pushnotifier/dist/index.js` is chosen as the entry point (due the `main` property in the `package.json`), but this is a Babel-transpiled CommonJS module (due to the build process), so it handles default exports differently: it has an extra `default` property (see [Babel 6 changes how it exports default](/q/33505992/4642212)). Using `new PushNotifier.default` instead of `new PushNotifier` is a workaround, but I’m sure better solutions exist… Not sure if the documentation is just incomplete or plain wrong.